# Using AWS DocumentDB with Sail.js configuration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to use AWS DocumentDB which is MongoDB compatible but unable successfully connect to the database.

Are there are any additional parameters that I need to pass into Sails.js datastores.js configuration?

Currently, my configs are as following:

```
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
url: 'mongodb://*****:*****@********.cluster-dasdsasd.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0',
```

Comment: First of all, DocumentDB is only 35% MongoDB Compatible See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/documents-are-everywhere for more technical info. Do you receive any errors ? are you failing at connection level ? or operational ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar thanks for the link, I wasn't aware DocumentDB is not 100% compatible. I will have to figure out how to create my own MongoDB instance

Comment: @SamAxe - You could check out MongoDB Atlas which is real MongoDB running in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Sails, i would suggest disable TLS in DocumentDB[1] and try connecting. I suspect that should fix the issue for you. I am wondering if it is able to find the pem file on you applications path (This part of URL - ?ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem)

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/security.encryption.ssl.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my solution was simply to set up MongoDB instance on the server.